# How to implement Facebook Account Kit in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, account-kit

I'm getting error Cannot read property 'loginWithPhoneNumber' of undefined

I've made developer account and setup App. I'm trying to implement this on android and have installed cordova-plugin-accountkit.

I tried this code on click:

```
(<any>window).AccountKitPlugin.loginWithPhoneNumber({
    useAccessToken: true,
    defaultCountryCode: "US",
  },function(res){
    console.log(res)
  },function(err){
     console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove fcm or firebase plugin from your app and then remove and add android platform again and build. It will work fine